# HElp in understanding difference between EM and MAP estimation methods

Tags: self-study, bayesian, estimation, expectation-maximization

**Problem 1:** The term $p_{\theta}(y_{1:N}|x_{1:N})p_{\theta}(x_{1:N})$ is the joint pdf, also called as the posterior. In EM, the complete data likelihood is the distribution of $x_1,\ldots,x_N,y_1,\ldots, y_N$ for which we write the same formulation as I have written. Then what is the difference between EM and Bayesian approach?

**Problem 2:** What is MAP and how is it different from what I wrote in Eq(2). If I were to estimate the parameters using MAP, then can somebody please show what  Eq(2) would become / what will be the changes?

**Problem 3:** In case of ML, how would Eq(2) change?

I don't need explanation on the methodology opted by the authors or for chaotic signal, but I want to understand what would be the difference in Eq(2) if $x$ was any kind of a signal (random, non-deterministic) --what pdf would be absent or present for Bayesian, EM and MAP techniques. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_maximization) is a specific class of algorithms, whereas [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) (including [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) as a special case) is a general approach to inference. As such, they're at different levels of description. EM and MAP aren't mutually exclusive; EM can be used to compute [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) (ML) or MAP estimates. MAP is a type of Bayesian inference, but is distinct from 'full' Bayesian inference (not a rigorous term).

In (2), you wrote an expression for the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$, given the parameters (this is not the posterior). It won't change for any of the methods you mentioned, nor will the likelihood function. Rather, Bayesian approaches differ from ML in that they impose [priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) on the parameters and are concerned with the [posterior distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability), whereas ML is only concerned with the [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function).

Say we have data $D$ and parameter vector $\theta$. The likelihood is $p(D \mid \theta)$ and the prior is $p(\theta)$. The posterior is given by Bayes' rule:

$$p(\theta \mid D) = \frac{p(D \mid \theta) p(\theta)}{p(D)}$$

We can think of $p(D)$ as a normalizing constant that forces the numerator to integrate to 1.

Say we'd like to obtain a point estimate of the parameters. ML seeks the parameters that maximize $p(D \mid \theta)$. MAP seeks the parameters that maximize $p(\theta \mid D)$. In a 'full' Bayesian approach, one might compute the mean of $p(\theta \mid D)$. These approaches also differ in how they deal with [interval estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_estimation).

Comment: Thank you for an easy explanation. From your answer, if I were to apply ML to estimate the parameters, then I should write $\mathbf{p(\theta|y_{1:N})} = \prod_{k=1}^NP_y(y[k]|x[k]) \prod_{k=1}^NP_x(x[k+1]|x[k]) $ but I am not confidently sure if this is correct. Therefore, it would be immensely helpful if you could kindly present the expressions assuming that the parameters are random variable, how would I write the Eq(2) (apply BAyes' rule) and for MAP and ML. This would really help to get a clear  picture.

Comment: No, the likelihood isn't the probability of the parameters given the data, please check my post again. It's not possible to write down an expression for the posterior (which you'd need for MAP and full Bayes) until you choose a prior for the parameters. The paper is doing ML estimation (using the EM algorithm), so you can take look at their equations. I think it would be much more helpful for you to try out these methods on some simple toy problems first, to get the concepts down. I recommend taking a look at Machine learning: A probabilistic perspective by Kevin Murphy.

Comment: Take a look at [these slides](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/Tutorials/Trinity.pdf) (found randomly on the web). They show an example for all 3 methods. Maximizing the log likelihood or log posterior is often more mathematically and computationally convenient. It's equivalent to maximizing the likelihood/posterior because the log is a monotonic function (so $\max f(x) = \max \log f(x)$).